# What is a good strategy for custom form validation in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

As my app is growing, I'm finding more need for more effective form validation. I personally don't like the angular built in validation that evaluates on field change. And there are always things it won't account for like verifying that a youtube video id is valid. Currently I'm doing validation in each forms controller. I have a function that looks like this. Each field has a message and if there is an error the message will appear red using ng-class.

```
$scope.validate = function (callback) {

    // reset default messages
    setMessages();

    // create shorter references
    var item = $scope.item,
        message = $scope.itemMessage;

    // title exists
    if (item.title === '') {
        message.title.message = 'You must give your item a title.';
        message.title.error = true;
        message.errors += 1;
    }

    // extract and clear video id with youtube api
    if ($scope.temp.video !== undefined && $scope.temp.video !== '') {

        var id = '';
        var url = $scope.temp.video.replace(/(>|<)/gi,'').split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);

        if(url[2] !== undefined) {
            id = url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_]/i);
            id = id[0];
        } else {
            id = url;
        }

        $http.get("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + id)
            .then(function (res) {
                $scope.item.video = id;
            }, function (res) {
                message.video.message = 'That is not a valid youtube video.';
                message.video.error = true;
                message.errors += 1;
                $scope.item.video = '';
            });
    }

    if (message.errors === 0) {
        callback();
    }

};
```

and then my actual form submission function calls $scope.validate(); passing it a function containing the $http.post(). The two major problems I see are that my callback isn't promise base so there's no guarantee it won't be called when an error exists and I've read again and again to keep large chunks of logic outside of your controller. I haven't found great examples of how this should be done but it must be a common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use Angular's built-in validation and have it not evaluate unless the form has been submitted:

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation#only-showing-errors-after-submitting-the-form

Essentially you set `$scope.submitted = true` when the form is submitted and set a conditional check so that error messages and classes are only shown when `$scope.submitted` is set.